AWS Lambda to RDS Postgres connection
I am relativley new to AWS, so any help is appricated!. I have set up a Lmabda fn to add a user to my RDS database when they are added in Cognito. I am trying to run a test directly through the Lambda console page. 
I keep getting this error running my test:
Test Event Name
basicTest

Response
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Failed to create user\",\"error\":\"no pg_hba.conf entry for host \\\"10.0.2.14\\\", user \\\"postgres\\\", database \\\"creditcuesdb\\\", no encryption\"}"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a Version: $LATEST
2024-07-25T06:44:51.478Z    10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a    INFO    Event:  {
  "request": {
    "userAttributes": {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "birthdate": "1990-01-01",
      "email": "john.doe@example.com",
      "user_id": "12345"
    }
  }
}
2024-07-25T06:44:51.478Z    10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a    INFO    Connecting to the database with the following configuration:
2024-07-25T06:44:51.478Z    10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a    INFO    Host: cue-prod-v1-mydbinstance-vjg6ptc3cfhh.cexk8pzzn0qz.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
2024-07-25T06:44:51.478Z    10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a    INFO    User: postgres
2024-07-25T06:44:51.478Z    10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a    INFO    Database: creditcuesdb
2024-07-25T06:44:51.478Z    10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a    INFO    Port: 5432
2024-07-25T06:44:51.600Z    10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a    ERROR   Error adding user to the database: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.0.2.14", user "postgres", database "creditcuesdb", no encryption
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:283:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:122:29)
    at Parser.parse (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:35:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 161,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '542',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
}
END RequestId: 10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a
REPORT RequestId: 10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a  Duration: 235.65 ms Billed Duration: 236 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 68 MB  
XRAY TraceId: 1-66a1f463-56211eef534b12b66a2845f4   SegmentId: 55c5e28e6950da0a Sampled: true

Request ID
10b5a33e-6fa2-4ca9-a0b2-7e0c0eee1b2a

Here is how the lambda is set up in the SAM Template:
  CreateUserLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: backend/database/
      Handler: src/create-user/lambda_handler.handler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !GetAtt DefaultSecurityGroup.GroupId
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref DefaultSubnetA
          - !Ref DefaultSubnetB

Here is the snippet from how the database and security groups are set up:
     # AWS Secrets Manager for DB Credentials
  DBInstanceSecret:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Description: PostgreSQL RDS database credentials
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "postgres"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        PasswordLength: 16
        ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\\'
      Name: !Sub "${DbName}-credentials"

  # VPC and Networking
  DefaultVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: "DefaultVPC"

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: "DefaultInternetGateway"

  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref DefaultVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref DefaultVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: "PublicRouteTable"

  PublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  DefaultSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref DefaultVPC
      CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

  DefaultSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref DefaultVPC
      CidrBlock: "10.0.2.0/24"
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, !GetAZs ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref DefaultSubnetA
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref DefaultSubnetB
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable

  DefaultDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: "Subnet group for RDS using default subnets"
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref DefaultSubnetA
        - !Ref DefaultSubnetB

  DefaultSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Default VPC security group"
      VpcId: !Ref DefaultVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"

  # RDS Database Instance
  MyDbInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: db.t3.micro
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      DBName: !Ref DbName
      Engine: postgres
      EngineVersion: 16.3
      MasterUsername: "postgres"
      MasterUserPassword: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref DBInstanceSecret, ':SecretString:password}}']]
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt DefaultSecurityGroup.GroupId
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DefaultDBSubnetGroup
      PubliclyAccessible: true

  # API Gateway
  ClientAPIGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: ClientAPIGateway
      Description: API Gateway for handling all client and Plaid API requests

  # Cognito Authorizer for the API
  CognitoAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      Name: CognitoAuthorizer
      Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
      RestApiId: !Ref ClientAPIGateway
      ProviderARNs:
        - !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.Arn

Some Steps I have already tried:

Created parameter group and set rds.foce_ssl to 0
Rebooted my RDS DB
Verified security groups are allow all for inbound and outbound
traffic


By default, RDS for PostgreSQL uses and expects all clients to connect using SSL/TLS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html
Talking about best practices, it is not recommended to turn off SSL by changing parameter from 1 to 0.
First, check your current AWS region and download the correct cert bundles. You can also double check this info from your RDS instance configuration details under Certificate authority.
Second, check your DB config from your code and try adding details about SSL such as

require: true
ca: <path-to-cert-bundle>

Then, retry and test your code with secure connection setup between your AWS Lambda function (within VPC) and your Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL instance.
